# SQL "OR" operator in Firebase Real Time Database Queries For Angular5 project angularfire2 5.0

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5, real-time

Want to get data using a parameter with multiple values for angular4  angularfire2 5.0 (AngularFireList) project. Like `participantString="abc" OR participantString="xyz"` in SQL.

Comment: can you show some your effort?

Comment: ` return this.db.list(this.enterprise_name + '/' + loginUser.replace('.' , '_') + '/conversations',
      ref => ref.orderByChild('participantsCS').equalTo(participantsCS)
      )`

I used this query two times and tried to combine the data in the frontend.But before getting the data of the second db call the codes is executing.

Comment: `return this.db.list(this.enterprise_name + '/' + loginUser.replace('.' , '_') + '/conversations',
      ref => ref.orderByChild('participantsCS').equalTo(participantsCS)`

Comment: @Kadioo Do you have a solution?